# Visual C++6 looking for text file in the "solution" directory rather than output directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, visual-c++, file-io

I have a VC++6 project and I have the following code snippet:

```
string s;
int i=0, indx;
ifstream myReadFile;

myReadFile.open("chanmap.txt");
```

For some reason, when I run the program, it is looking for the text file in the "solution"/root/dsw directory rather than the output directory (i.e. Debug folder) This is a legacy project, so I'm sure that some settings were probably mangled here and there. But this IDE is almost as old as me and very foreign. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MSVS By default sets the working directory to the directory where the project and source code files are located.

Comment: When you run it in the debugger?  You need to set the working directory in the options for the solution.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, when I'm debugging. But would this hold for a Release build too?

Comment: @audiFanatic -- You can debug release builds in Visual Studio, and you can run debug builds outside of Visual Studio, so your question is not clear.  When you say "release build" do you mean when you run it outside of Visual Studio?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie correct

Comment: @audiFanatic - Well, you're at the mercy of the relative path issue.  I guess wherever the .exe file is run is where that file needs to be located, unless you set the working directory programatically.

Comment: That's the problem. When I put the file in the same directory as the exe, it does not work. However, when I put it one level up, it does.

Answer (score 0):

For both Debug and Release projects, specify same path in project settings **Debugging -> Working Directory**:

[image]
Other than this, ensure you run the program from Windows Explorer (or command propmpt from the same path). You may need to create a shortcut, where you'd specify **directory**.

Since you are on Windows, you can also use [SetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) within your program.

Comment: I'm using VC++6, not quite the same. But there is a spot for the working directory. Not sure that I can use path macros unfortunately.

Comment: Eh, I've gotten help with it before here. Not my first choice of IDE. it's unfortunately what's been forced upon me.

Comment: I don't have any access to VC6. I cannot show the screenshot, nor the instructions to set current directory. Can you not find how to set "Current working directory" for current project? How hard is that?